# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания 7

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли оформлено следующее предложение? Особенно интересует оборот **как в прошлом, так и в настоящем**... Изначально он был выделен тире с двух сторон, а тире после **а сегодня** не было.

Важнейшей причиной такого положения является, как в прошлом, так и в настоящем,   недофинансирование отрасли, а сегодня – и недостаточно активная работа ее представителей в госструктурах, которые не уделяют никакого внимания изобретательству и образованию.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаемый вариант:

Важнейшей причиной такого положения — **как в прошлом, так и в настоящем** — является недофинансирование отрасли, **а сейчас еще и**  недостаточно активная работа ее представителей в госструктурах, которые не уделяют никакого внимания изобретательству и образованию.

1) Вставка нужна, ее нужно выделить из основного текста, причем в удобном месте. Две основные причины должны ясно читаться, эта часть текста должна быть компактной.

2) После сегодня "пауза" (и тире)  нежелательны, "сейчас ещё" (вместо "сегодня") —  лучше вписывается в текст.

Answer (score 0):

Немного изменим порядок слов: *Важнейшей причиной такого положения как в прошлом, так и в настоящем, является...*

Но все равно фраза не очень. "В настоящем" и "сегодня" — это ведь одно и то же? А предложение звучит так, как будто это разные вещи.